# How can I make my drop-down menu more mobile-friendly?

Tags: html, css, mobile, nav

I am using the the following HTML and CSS code for devices with a max-width of 480px.

How can I:

1. Add the word "Menu" before the links?
2. Display only "Menu"?
3. Click on "Menu" to reveal links and then sub-links?
4. Make "Menu", links and sublinks 100% of device width?

Please note, my knowledge of web design is limited to basic HTML and CSS. And this is my first go at designing a website.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```css
#menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3rem;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    z-index: 999;
}

#menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: #0000ff;
 color: #ffffff;
}

#menu ul > li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 height: auto;
 width: 20%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#menu li > a {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #0000ff;
 color: #ffffff;
}

#menu li > span {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #0000ff;
 color: #ffffff;
}

#menu ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: static;
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}

#menu ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 float: none;
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

#menu ul ul li > a {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
 color: #0000ff;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

#menu li:hover > span {
 color: #0000ff;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">

    <ul>

        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>

        <li><span>ABOUT</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about/history.html">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="about/champions.html">Champions</a></li>
                <li><a href="about/presidents.html">Presidents</a></li>
                <li><a href="about/committee.html">Committee</a></li>
                <li><a href="about/rules.html">Rules</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    
        <li><span>BOOK</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="book/functions.html">Functions</a></li>
                <li><a href="book/suite.html">Suite</a></li>
                <li><a href="book/lounge.html">Lounge</a></li>
                <li><a href="book/bar.html">Bar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    
        <li><span>COMPS</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="comps/fixtures.html">Fixtures</a></li>
                <li><a href="comps/gents.html">Gents</a></li>
                <li><a href="comps/ladies.html">Ladies</a></li>
                <li><a href="comps/winners.html">Winners</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    
        <li><span>CONTACT</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="contact/details.html">Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="membership/join.html">Join</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact/map.html">Map</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
</nav>
```

Comment: _“Please note, my knowledge of web design is limited to basic HTML and CSS. And this is my first go at designing a website.”_ - that still doesn’t mean you’re free from having to do your own basic research, and show us an attempt.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, though your comment was far from helpful. Granted, my research may be "basic" and perhaps I should have showed "an attempt". But since I first got interested in web design over a month ago, I have adopted the Boy Scout motto of "I will do my best". I wish you well in the future. Peter.

Answer (score 2):

Please check following example

```css
/********** Start RESET **********
 AUTHOR: Osvaldas Valutis, www.osvaldas.info
*/
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 *behavior: url( '/theme/js/boxsizing.htc' );
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sup, sub, tt, var, b, u, i, center, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, table, tr, th, td, thead, tbody, tfoot, caption, form, fieldset, legend, input, textarea, select, label, applet, object, iframe, audio, video, canvas, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary {
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-weight: inherit;
 font-style: inherit;
 line-height: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
html {
 font-size: 100%;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 -o-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #fff;
}
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary {
 display: block;
}
audio, canvas, video {
 display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
}
audio:not([controls]) {
 display: none;
}
canvas {
 -ms-touch-action: double-tap-zoom;
}
 [hidden] {
display: none;
}
a {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #000;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
small {
 font-size: 75%;
}
big {
 font-size: 125%;
}
em {
 font-style: italic;
}
strong {
 font-weight: bold;
}
ins {
 text-decoration: none;
}
del {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}
sup, sub {
 font-size: 75%;
 line-height: 0;
}
sup {
 vertical-align: super;
}
sub {
 vertical-align: sub;
}
pre {
 display: block;
 overflow: auto;
}
code {
 font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
ul, ol {
 list-style: none;
}
table {
 table-layout: auto;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 0;
 empty-cells: hide;
}
img {
 vertical-align: middle;
 -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
svg:not(:root) {
 overflow: hidden;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
input, textarea {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
 vertical-align: baseline;
*vertical-align: middle;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
button, input {
 line-height: normal;
*overflow: visible;
}
table button, table input {
*overflow: auto;
}
button, input[type='button'], input[type='reset'], input[type='submit'] {
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-appearance: button;
}
textarea {
 overflow: auto;
 vertical-align: top;
}
input[type='search']::-webkit-search-decoration, input[type='search']::-webkit-search-cancel-button, input[type='search']::-webkit-search-results-button, input[type='search']::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
display: none;
}
input[type='search'] {
 -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
input[type='radio'] {
 -webkit-appearance: radio;
}
input[type='checkbox'] {
 -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
}
input::-ms-clear {
display: none;
}
input[type='password']::-ms-reveal {
display: none;
}
.clearfix:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
}
* html .clearfix {
 zoom: 1;
}
*:first-child+html .clearfix {
 zoom: 1;
}
.cleaner {
 height: 0;
 line-height: 0;
 clear: both;
}

/********** End RESET **********/



html {
 font-size: 100%;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Noticia Text', serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 background-color: #f7efeb;
 padding: 1.25em; /* 20 */
}
body, a, a:hover {
 color: #111;
}
a {
 -webkit-transition: color .3s ease;
 -moz-transition: color .3s ease;
 -ms-transition: color .3s ease;
 -o-transition: color .3s ease;
 transition: color .3s ease;
}
a, a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
#nav {
 width: 60em; /* 1000 */
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -30em; /* 30 480 */
}
#nav > a {
 display: none;
}
#nav li {
 position: relative;
}
#nav li a {
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
}
#nav li a:active {
 background-color: #c00 !important;
}
#nav span:after {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 0.313em solid transparent; /* 5 */
 border-bottom: none;
 border-top-color: #efa585;
 content: '';
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 right: -0.313em; /* 5 */
}
/* first level */

   #nav > ul {
 height: 3.75em; /* 60 */
 background-color: #e15a1f;
}
#nav > ul > li {
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em; /* 24 */
 line-height: 2.5em; /* 60 (24) */
 text-align: center;
}
#nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a {
 border-right: 1px solid #cc470d;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > a, #nav > ul:not( :hover ) > li.active > a {
 background-color: #cc470d;
}
/* second level */

    #nav li ul {
 background-color: #cc470d;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#nav li:not( :first-child ):hover ul {
 left: -1px;
}
#nav li ul a {
 font-size: 1.25em; /* 20 */
 border-top: 1px solid #e15a1f;
 padding: 0.75em; /* 15 (20) */
}
#nav li ul li a:hover, #nav li ul:not( :hover ) li.active a {
 background-color: #e15a1f;
}
 @media only screen and ( max-width: 62.5em ) /* 1000 */ {
#nav {
 width: 100%;
 position: static;
 margin: 0;
}
}
 @media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ) /* 640 */ {
html {
 font-size: 75%; /* 12 */
}
#nav {
 position: relative;
 top: auto;
 left: auto;
}
#nav > a {
 width: 3.125em; /* 50 */
 height: 3.125em; /* 50 */
 text-align: left;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 background-color: #e15a1f;
 position: relative;
}
#nav > a:before, #nav > a:after {
 position: absolute;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 top: 35%;
 left: 25%;
 right: 25%;
 content: '';
}
#nav > a:after {
 top: 60%;
}
#nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type, #nav:target > a:last-of-type {
 display: block;
}
/* first level */

   #nav > ul {
 height: auto;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#nav:target > ul {
 display: block;
}
#nav > ul > li {
 width: 100%;
 float: none;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
 height: auto;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 0 0.833em; /* 20 (24) */
}
#nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a {
 border-right: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cc470d;
}
/* second level */

    #nav li ul {
 position: static;
 padding: 1.25em; /* 20 */
 padding-top: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />



<nav id="nav" role="navigation"> <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a> <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>
      <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href=""><span>Blog</span></a>
          <ul>
        <li><a href="">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
        </li>
    <li> <a href=""><span>Work</span></a>
          <ul>
        <li><a href="">Web Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Typography</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Front-End</a></li>
      </ul>
        </li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```